# An example where $f:X \to X$ is not a contraction map but $f \circ f$ is?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Can anyone give me one example where $X$ is a complete metric space, $f:X \to X$ is not a contraction map, but $f \circ f$ is?

I thought in terms of having a unique fixed point, also but couldn't find it properly.

Answer (score 8):

Consider $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y) = (0,2x)$.  If $p = (1,0)$ then $d(0,p) = 1$ but $d(f(0), f(p)) = 2$.  On the other hand, $f \circ f = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=\mathbb R$ and $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{3}x&\text{if }x\leq 0\\
-2x&\text{if }x>0
\end{cases}$$

Then $f(f(x))=\frac{2x}{3}$.

This has the advantage that $f$ is $1-1$ and onto.

Answer (score 3):

To be a contraction map requires the distance $d(f(x),f(y)) \lt d(x,y)$ for distinct all points $x,y$.

Consider a map on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$ f(x) =  \begin{cases}  x/3 &\text{ when } x \gt 0, \\  |x| &\text{ when } x \le 0 .
  \end{cases} $$

Then clearly $f \circ f$ is a contraction mapping, but when $x,y \lt 0$, $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y|$, so $f$ itself is not a contraction mapping.