# example of a map $T: \Bbb{R^2} \rightarrow \Bbb{R^2}$ such that $T^2$ is a contraction mapping but T is not

Tags: real-analysis

So I proved that if $T^n: X \rightarrow X$ is a contraction mapping from a complete metric space into itself, then T has a unique fixed point.

Now I'm being asked to come up with an example of a map $T: \Bbb{R^2} \rightarrow \Bbb{R^2}$ such that $T^2$ is a contraction mapping but T is not.

I think it's going to have something to do with the Euclidean metric, and I know by the above that $T^2(T(x_0)) = T(T^2(x_0)) = T(x_0)$, i.e. $T$ and $T^2$ will have the same unique fixed point.

I need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: See the first answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020587.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Make $T$ first contract *half* of $\Bbb R^2$ (for some reasonable definition of "half"), and then swap the two halves.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the transformation
\begin{align}
T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: I understand why $T^2$ is a contraction here. Are there are lots of nilpotent matrices for which this would work? And the fixed point here is the zero vector?

Comment: @AndyDufresne In two dimensions, any nilpotent linear map will work (i.e., already be zero when squared). And $0$ is a fixed point of every linear map

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Not all nilpotent linear maps work. It has to not be a contraction. For instance, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & \frac12\\
0 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ doesn't work, while $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 2\\
0 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ does.

Comment: I still have to work out the estimate to prove this. So I have to show that $d(T(x),T(y)) > \alpha d(x,y)$. Using the Euclidean metric, with $0 < \alpha < 1$ and writing $x = (x_1,x_2)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2)$, that requires $|x_2-y_2| > \alpha|\sqrt((x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2)|$. I am thinking Cauchy-Schwartz here? The alpha term is throwing me off.

Comment: @AnfyDufresne If you can find a _single pair_ of points $x,y$ such that $d(x,y)\leq d(T(x),T(y))$, you will have proven that $T$ cannot be a contraction. Of course, for some non-contractions there are no such pairs, and then you have to think about $\alpha$ and stuff and be more thorough.

Comment: There is equality with any pair of points (0,a) and (0,b).

Comment: @AndiDufresne You're right, so there is!